# Integrate Cloud Functions for Firebase with Braintree

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, braintree

I'm trying to see if it's possible to integrate Cloud Functions for Firebase with Braintree. I created a project for Cloud Functions according to [the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started).
In the project directory I ran: `npm install braintree`.
I modified `index.js` for testing purposes to be the following:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

var braintree = require("braintree");

var gateway = braintree.connect({
                            environment: 
braintree.Environment.Sandbox,
                            merchantId: "useYourMerchantId",
                            publicKey: "useYourPublicKey",
                            privateKey: "useYourPrivateKey"
                            });


// // Create and Deploy Your First Cloud Functions
// // https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/write-firebase-
functions
//
 exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  response.send("Hello from Firebase!");
//gateway.clientToken.generate({}, function (err, response) {
    //response.send(response.clientToken);
//});
 });
```

When I tried to deploy this test function I got the error

> Error parsing triggers: Cannot find module 'braintree'

I'm new to Firebase, Cloud Functions, and node.js and would appreciate any input on how to import Braintree to Firebase Functions project.

Comment: I think you're trying to cover a bit too much ground in one go here. If you're new to Node.js, I'd recommend starting with just calling the Braintree API from Node.js. If you're new to Firebase, I'd recommend interacting with Firebase from it's Node.js SDK (or its Web SDK if you're more familiar with JavaScript in a web context). Once you have experience with those two, you'll be in a much better shape to add Cloud Functions to the mix,

Comment: That said, the quick fix for the likely cause of the error is below. :-)

Comment: Great post because it shows an example of how to make a call from Firebase to BrainTree.  I haven't seen any other succinct example of how to set this up.  Would be nice if they added a snippet like this to the official BrainTree docs. Very cool, thanks.  The one thing I found to be careful about is that when you uncomment the `gateway.clientToken.generate(..)` block, make sure to give a unique name to the 2nd `response` param as it's a different object from the outter one - eg: `gateway.clientToken.generate({}, function (err, gatewayResponse) {..}`

Answer (score 7):

It looks like Cloud Functions for Firebase is not picking up the `braintree` module. Like most Node.js environments, Cloud Functions reads the dependencies from `package.json`. When you install a module with `npm` you can tell it to also write it to `package.json` by adding `--save` to the command line. So:

```
npm install braintree --save
```

Answer (score 6):

You have the Node.js package `braintree` missing.

Your Firebase project has a directory called `functions`.
In the terminal, go to the `functions` directory by `$ cd {your project dir}/functions`
And then `npm i braintree --save`.
I hope that it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

change current directory to functions:-  `cd functions`
then install braintree in that folder using npm: - `npm i braintree`
then import braintree : - `var braintree = require('braintree');`
now everything should work fine.

Note:- if you have not enabled payment in firebase, it will though 'unexpectedError' in the http response.